# Include different logback.xml in production build

Tags: java, maven, logback

I use Maven for building and would like to use `logback-debugging.xml` for developing but package another , `logback-info.xml`, to the final product.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following Maven configuration:

```
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>dev</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <filtering>true</filtering><!-- if it is neccessary -->
                    <directory>src/main/logging/develop</directory><!-- from -->
                    <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath><!-- to -->
                    <includes><!-- what -->
                        <include>logback.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In Maven settings file, we can activate one profile per default:

```
<settings>
  [..]
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>development</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  [..]
</settings>
```

Another way is to move the default profile configuration to the "normal" pom build section.

To activate the development profile, pass the debug flag via command line, e.g. `mvn package -Ddev`

Answer (score -1):

Logback searches for configuration files in a specific order (see [the docs here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)). The first place it looks is for a file called logback-test.xml in your classpath. Since you're using maven, include that file in your **test/resources** directory. That way when you're running any of your tests, the logback-test.xml file is used. For your production code, include logback.xml in your **main/resources** directory.